# JQuery and expand/collapse function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote this very simple code to expand and collapse a text when pressing a button, but it doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.expand').click(function(){
    $('.content').slideToggle('slow');
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="sitesection">
    <p class="expand"><a href="#">Click Here To Display The Content</a></p>
    <p class="content">Hello World!"</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click on "Click here to display the content", nothing happens.

Comment: because you bind an event to an element before it exists.

Comment: Define it at the end or use `$(document).load(....` method

Comment: Can I interest you in `<details><summary>Click here to display the content</summary><p>Hello world!</p></details>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put your code to bottom or use DOM ready event

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="sitesection">
    <p class="expand"><a href="#">Click Here To Display The Content</a></p>
    <p class="content">Hello World!"</p>
</div>
<script>
$('.expand').click(function(){
    $('.content').slideToggle('slow');
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks it works! can you explain (or link me an explanation) why the script should be put at the bottom of the body instead of the head?

Comment: @alessandro 
when the script executing elements must be in DOM
https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: @Alessandro the click event is not bind to anything if you do it before the dom elements are created. If you place the .click at the end the dom is ready or you specify in your script document.ready before binding the click event.

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="sitesection">
    <p class="expand"><a href="#">Click Here To Display The Content</a></p>
    <p class="content">Hello World!"</p>
</div>
<script>
$('.expand').click(function(){
    $('.content').slideToggle('slow');
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Or must call javascript after load document.

Comment: "Try this [code]" answers are not useful. Please explain what you changed, why you changed it, and why it solves the problem.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol i last code